# SQLite SELECT statment on one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, select

I have table with colums: game-type-score-time and I want select best scores at one taype of game. And at that score I want to heve the lowest time at thet specific game,type, and score.

I tride with group by but I didn't get what I want.

```
SELECT game, type, MAX(score),MIN(time)
FROM table
GROUP BY game,type
```

What I want:
If this is my table:

```
 0/1/0/672
 0/1/0/749
 0/1/1/2091
 0/1/1/3252

 0/5/0/5088
 0/5/0/5504
 0/5/1/6482
 0/5/2/9408
 0/5/2/24616
 0/5/3/6592 
 0/5/4/8706

 1/1/0/700
 1/1/1/1151

 1/5/5/4808

 3/1/1/1038
```

I want output like this:

```
 0/1/1/2091
 0/5/4/8706
 1/1/1/1151
 1/5/5/4808
 3/1/1/1038
```

What is the most eficenty way to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in a single aggregation:

```
SELECT s.game, s.type, s.score, MIN(t.time) AS time
FROM (
    SELECT tt.game, tt.type, MAX(tt.score) AS score 
    FROM table tt 
    GROUP BY tt.game, tt.type
) s 
INNER JOIN table t ON s.game = t.game AND s.type = t.type AND s.score = t.score
GROUP BY s.game, s.type, s.score
```